# To access object properties based on the id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 api's called `teachers` and `sessions`.

`teachers` **JSON** file:

```
   [
      {
        "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
        "id": "01"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Basilio Gregg",
        "id": "02"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
        "id": "03"
      },
      {
        "teacherName": "Cole Moxom",
        "id": "04"
      }
    ]
```

`sessions` **JSON** file:

```
[
    {
        "id":"001",
        "sessionName": "Chemistry",
        "notes": "Chemistry is the study of matter, its properties",
        "teacherId": "01"<==========
    },
    {
        "id":"002",
        "sessionName": "Physics",
        "notes": "Physics is the natural science that studies matter and its motion ",
        "teacherId": "03"
    },
    {
        "id":"003",
        "sessionName": "Maths",
        "notes": "Mathematics includes the study of such topics as quantity",
        "teacherId": "01"<=========

    },
    {
        "id":"004",
        "sessionName": "Biology",
       "notes": "Biology is the natural science that studies life and living organisms",
        "teacherId": "04"
    }
]
```

Now i am displaying all the teachers in the template like this:

[image]

In the **sessions** JSON, I have mentioned the **teacherID**, I want to display the `sessions` of the **particular  teacher** based upon the `teachersID`.

For ex the sessions (Chemistry & Maths) contains **teacherID** as (01),So i want to display these 2 sessions(Chemistry & Maths) under **Teacher 1(i,e Binky Alderwick)** Like this:

[image]

I should get all the properties of the `session` object based on the `teacherId`.

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-5ew3n4)**

Comment: Use a forEach on the teachers array and use sessions.filter() inside I will edit the stack blitz and let you know

Comment: You gonna try or should I edit the stack blitz?

Comment: I see that your question is answered. (using the same logic almost)

Comment: Anyhow i got the solution, thank you too..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one function which returns array of sessions for a particular teacher.

**Example: app.component.ts**

```
getSessionForTeacher(teacherId) {
    return this.sessions ? this.sessions.filter(x => x.teacherId === teacherId) : [];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sessions</td>
        <td><br>
      <div *ngFor="let item of getSessionForTeacher(teacher.id)">
      <h2>{{item.sessionName}}</h2>
      <p>{{item.notes}}</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-5fz2mr) Here is full demostration of your problem.